# How to copy a worksheet as values to another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a macro that copies my sheet called "Input Form" and copies it to a new Workbook.

I want to change this code to only copy the sheet over as values.

```
Dim filename As String
Dim path As String
filename = "Invoice" & Range("D13") & "_Store" & Range("D17") & "_" & Format(Range("D12"), "yyyy-mm-dd")
path = Worksheets("Filepaths").Range("C4")
Sheets("Input Form").Select
Sheets("Input Form").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=path & filename, FileFormat:=xlExcel12
```

**I have looked at similar answers, but their original code is so different from mine, that the answers do not apply**

Thanks in advance

Update: Trying BigBens suggestion

```
Dim filename As String
Dim path As String
filename = "Invoice" & Range("D13") & "_Store" & Range("D17") & "_" & Format(Range("D12"), "yyyy-mm-dd")
path = Worksheets("Filepaths").Range("C4")
Sheets("Input Form").Select
Sheets("Input Form").Copy
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange
.Value = .Value
End With
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs filename:=path & filename, FileFormat:=xlExcel12
```

Comment: Perhaps see the linked duplicates (and there are many others), or do something like `With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).UsedRange`, `.Value = .Value`, `End With` before the `SaveAs`. Please ping back here if you still can't get it to work.

Comment: I am a beginner developer and do need a bit more help. I'm having trouble translating the concepts provided into making the appropriate changes to my code

Comment: Did you try adding the three lines of code in my comment?

Comment: Yes, I've updated my original post to reflect it. Could you confirm I've done it correctly?

Comment: Looks good - so did it work, or not?

Comment: Yes, its fixed it. Thank you so much BigBen!

Comment: You should consider posting this as an answer and accepting it so others can see that your problem was solved!